# Define 2d array with dynamic first dimension and static second in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to define int array in which first dimension is choosen dynamically but second is static --
something like `int array[][8]`. Unfortunatelly I can not allocate such array dynamically. `int ary[][8] = new int[11][8];` Produces error:

```cpp
error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘array’
    6 |     int array[][8] = new int[11][8];
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2d.cpp:6:20: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

or when I try following code:

```cpp
int array[][8] = new int*[11];
array[0] = new int[8];
```

I get

```
2d2.cpp:6:22: error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘array’
    6 |     int array[][8] = new int*[11];
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2d2.cpp:6:22: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
2d2.cpp:7:25: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [8]’
    7 |     array[0] = new int[8];
```

Is that even possible in c++?

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<int, 8>> myArray(11);`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::vector` and `std::array`:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using MyArray = std::vector<std::array<int, 8>>;
    MyArray arr {11};
    for (int i {0}; i < 8; ++i)
        arr[i][i] = i;
    for (const auto& v : arr) {
        for (auto x : v) {
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39957826a462ce73)</kbd>**

Comment: This is not what I want. I'm confused about c++ syntax in regard of 2d arrays and I want to clarify it.

Comment: @Trismegistos It is how to achieve what you want to achieve.  Arrays in C++ are dumb, and only a higher level of abstraction can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @Trismegistos  Why not? It's exactly what you asked for: "int array in which first dimension is choosen dynamically but second is static".

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question:

```cpp
int (*array)[8] = new int[11][8];
```

I forgot how bad C++ rules for creating type definitions -- especially including pointers, arrays and function pointers -- are. I added missing parentheses around array and now it is fine.

Comment: So how is this any advantage over the `std::vector/std::array` version?  You have to now concern yourself with deallocating that memory.  Modern C++ programs should refrain from using `new[]`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There's no need to be aggressive. Yes, if this were a "real problem," I'd suggest using that too, and if you hadn't mentioned it I would have commented that as an alternative. But expressions like `new int[11][8]` are part of the language, like it or not, and there is value in knowing how to use them. Also, if the only concern is remembering to `delete` the memory, `auto arr = std::make_unique<int[][8]>(11);` should work fine. `std::vector` may be conceptually overkill.